# If $X$, $Y$ are IID Gaussians, why is $U= X + 2Y$ independent from $V= Y-2Y$?

Tags: probability, random-variables

It seems to me that if $U$ and $V$ are made up of the same variables $X$ and $Y$, then they should be related in some way. I know that the covariance is 0, but dependent variables can in some cases have 0 covariance correct?

Comment: It is a special property of Gaussian variables that zero covariance implies independence. You therefore need to show that $X+2Y$ and $X-2Y$ are themselves Gaussian and have zero covariance.

Comment: @Ian: They need to be jointly Gaussian: [individually Gaussian is not enough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent)

Answer (score 2):

It is known that for gaussian measures independent=uncorrelated.

But, if I properly understand, you are worried about some expected relation. It is an analogy from the linear algebra, but I hope, that it may resolve your doubts. If $X$, $Y$ are lineary indepent, such are $X+2Y$ and $X-2Y$.